# Heroku code=H10 app crashed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am new to Heroku and rails. I've read articles to create APIs for my phone app.

I have succeeded in creating locally and when I run server, the APIs respond correctly, but when I try to use the heroku link to my app I get error in log\console saying

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/v1/carbrands/" host=b-taxi-server.herokuapp.com request_id=283223f5-f68d-4c4a-bb70-3346a2e3327f fwd="156.205.91.128" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=b-taxi-server.herokuapp.com request_id=10510255-6149-4583-8886-6bbb69f37aaa fwd="156.205.91.128" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

/app/app/controllers/Api/V1/carbrands_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Api (NameError)
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Carbrands controller is under $$\app\controllers\Api\V1\carbrands_controller.rb

I've controller carbrands_controller.rb which has following

```
class Api::V1::CarbrandsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def index
        output_brands
     end

    def output_brands
      brands = CarBrand.all
      #@trips = Trip.all
      if brands
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render :json => brands.to_json, status: status } #see if you want to send the cars for each user or not
        end
      else
        output_error(401, @noBrands_found)
      end    

    end

end
```

in my routes I have

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #api routes path
  #devise_for :users
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :carbrands,  only: [:create, :index]
    end
  end
end
```

I am not sure what is wrong to be honest. I've pushed the code using `git push heroku master`

How do I fix that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution for me.

the controller was under  app\controllers\Api\V1\  . Hence the "A" and the "V" was capital. I needed to rename the folder to be with "a" and "v". Then it worked!!.

Also, sometimes the git doesn't notice these changes so what I did is deleting the whole folder "Api" >> commit it >>> recreate it with "api" then commit it. After that I pushed and heroku worked